# ARM Template - Get specific host key of a function

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have to create a host key (use in API Management backend) for my Azure function with a name passed in via a parameter.
I can't find out how I can use the the listKeys to fetch one particular host key by it's name.

I'm creating the host key like this, if I do not add my output this is working properly

```
{
                            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/host/functionKeys",
                            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
                            "name": "[concat(variables('functionSite-name'), '/default/',variables('apim-name'))]",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": "[variables('apim-name')]"
                            }
                        }
```

I tried this, got it from another post but it returns the error :
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"InvalidResourceNamespace","message":"The resource namespace 'GetVersionPOCApiManagement' is invalid."}]}

```
[listkeys(concat(variables('functionSite-name'), '/host/default/'),'2016-08-01').functionKeys[variables('apim-name')]]
```

'functionSite-name' is the name of my Azure Function (Microsoft.Web/sites)
'apim-name' is the name of the created host key (Microsoft.Web/sites/host/functionKeys)

As a reference my full script, I use a deployment because my Azure function is in another resource group and I need to create the host key and then add it to a key vault. After that I have to configure the API Management instance to use this Azure Function.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
    },
    "variables": {
        "apim-name": "eud-sse-poc-apim",
        "api-name": "GetVersionPOCApiManagement",
        "functionSite-name": "GetVersionPOCApiManagement",
        "functionSite-ResourceGroup": "eud-sse-poc-datafactory-rg"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
            "name": "azureFunctionDeployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[variables('functionSite-ResourceGroup')]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/host/functionKeys",
                            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
                            "name": "[concat(variables('functionSite-name'), '/default/',variables('apim-name'))]",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": "[variables('apim-name')]"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "outputs": {
                        "hostKey": {                            
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "[listkeys(concat(variables('functionSite-name'), '/host/default/'),'2016-08-01').functionKeys[variables('apim-name')]]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found it myself, was looking at the wrong part

```
[listkeys(concat(variables('functionSite-name'), '/host/default/'),'2016-08-01').functionKeys[variables('apim-name')]]
```

Should be

```
[listKeys(concat(resourceId(variables('functionSite-ResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Web/sites', 'GetVersionPOCApiManagement'), '/host/default'), '2016-08-01').functionKeys[variables('apim-name')]]
```

So I can confirm that you can eaisly access StringDictionary in an ARM template